# Laravel page doesn't display properly

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade, issue-tracking

I have just finished a Laravel project on which I have been working for some time (administrator area, user area). The problem is that one of the pages shows only part of its content in the browser without showing an error message. I have checked the controller, routes, and views and don't think the issue is there. On the other hand, when I check the source code of the page on chrome with CTRL + U I find the code of the content supposed to be displayed (a payment form with the associated methods). I would like to know how I could fix this problem or at least know where it comes from
thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. We can't really help you with this without more information such as code for your view(s), controller(s) and route(s).

Comment: if you see your content int ctrl+u but not in regular view, it must be a css/js issue